The method is undefined when trying to use it inside other classes in src main
Experiencing an issue while trying to generate methods using lombok. The issue is "The method / constructor / etc is undefined for the type ...". I encounter it for any classes that are located in src/main/java, but, when using the same one in src/test/java, during testing I dont get any errors and the results are correct. Let me explain the situation a bit more:

if I try to use a generated method inside another class in src/main to get some data it throws an error about undefined method.

When I remove lombok methods and write my own, there are no issues whatsoever.

The error is not present if I use lombok generated methods inside classes in src/test/java directory


Code snippet:
public class DroolsRuleParsing {
    public static String checkLombokMethods(RuleFormat rule) {
        String constraintItems = null;
    
        if (rule.getRuleType().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
            constraintItems = "$hit_idList contains $appliedrule_hitId";
        }
        if (rule.getRuleType().equalsIgnoreCase("hit")) {
            constraintItems = "$hit_id == $appliedrule_hitId";
        }
        return constraintItems;
    }
}

Error: The method getRuleType() is undefined for the type RuleFormat
If I remove this method and try to use .getRuleType() in src/test/java, then there are no errors:
@Test
    public void testRuleGeneration() throws Exception {
        LOG.info("Testing rule generation from JSON");
        RuleFormat RuleData = new RuleFormat();
        RuleData.setId("unique_id_4");
        RuleData.setUid("rule_4");
        RuleData.setName("Rule 4");
        RuleData.setVersion("ver1");
        RuleData.setRuleType("item");
        LOG.info("check lombok getters {}", RuleData.getRuleType());

2024-09-26 17:06:12,572 [main] INFO  check lombok getters item

I am using mvn clean test; mvn clean install to check if created method works.
I've tried:

following sintallation guide on the official website to install Lombok - https://projectlombok.org/setup/maven - instruction here

fiddled with configuration in pom file, some adviced to remove "scope" from the pom.xml - did not help

reinstalling VS code extensions with Lombok (Lombok Annotations Support for VS Code)



As I was using a test project from Drools "Getting started" section, the packaging value in pom.xml was set to kjar. With this setup lombok methods are not working and I was not able to make them work. Switching packaging to jar solved an error, though Drools rules stopped working in the same project.

So are you saying that you could not get Drools and Lombok to work together? In other words, it's either Drools or Lombok but not both?

I am not proficient in Java enough to give a definitive answer to it, just my observations and what helped me at least partly fix problem.It is important to note that I am using RuleUnit API - when switching to jar packaging it returns error - Cannot find any rule unit.
